# why i get 405 Unsopported media type when using [FromBody] attribute in web api HttpPost method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

when i use [FromBody] attribute in the web api method, i cant call the api from postman and when i call i receive the status: 415 Unsupported Media Type error. but if i remove the attribute ,i can call the api with post man but the argument sent to the api is null.

i searched my error but found no correct answer. i removed the attribute but no data filled in the argument

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] UserDto userDto)
{
...
}
```

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult:Information: Executing HttpStatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 415
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action DatingSite.Controllers.AuthController.Register (DatingSite) in 146.5064ms

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] UserDto userDto)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        if(await _repo.UserExist(userDto.Username))
        {
            return BadRequest("user name is used before");
        }

        User newUser=new User{
            UserName=userDto.Username
        };
        var createdUser=await _repo.Register(newUser,userDto.Password);
        return StatusCode(201);
    }
```

and i send this with postman,with empty budy,but i tried with budy with raw data like this:
 http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register
{
"username":"someUser",
"password":"somePassword"
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LOQH.png)

i'm using post method.
{"username":"someUserName","password":"somePassword"}

```
public class UserDto
{
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(8,MinimumLength=4)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's an unsupported media type, can you please post the code/set up you're using to test the API. It's to do with the content type you're sending

Comment: can you post screen shots of your postman set up?

Comment: If you're using [FromBody] - you must use POST, with body containing valid UserDto  object in json (or whatever type you use).

Comment: do you have the Content-Type header set to application/json in the postman request?

Comment: thanks @David-Yenglin, that was the problem. i did not set the content-type. after setting it, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

add a header for the content, see below

[image]